# Parsing proprety info C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing

Guys i've the following loop, and if is a List i've to loop again, until here i'm okay, but inside this another loop I got a problem, because i've to loop not in "propretyinfo", i've to loop in object of this PropretyInfo and get this values, i've tried a hard parse here :

```
(List<ItemDeMescla>)objeto.GetValue(objeto, null)
```

But it was throwing an excepetion, any idea how to parse it and works?

```
foreach (PropertyInfo objeto in processo.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    corpoEmail += CriarLinhaEmail(objeto.Name, Convert.ToString(objeto.GetValue(processo, null)), false);

    if (objeto.PropertyType.IsGenericType && (objeto.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<>)))
    {
        List<ItemDeMescla> itensMescla = (List<ItemDeMescla>)objeto.GetValue(objeto, null);
        foreach (ItemDeMescla item in itensMescla)
        {
            tabelasAux.Add(CriarTabelaInternaEmail<ItemDeMescla>(item, objeto.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

The error stack:

```
    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
   at SACG.Services.Integracao.Integracao.Utils.MontarCorpoEmail[T](T processo, String mensagem) in c:\Projetos\Cotrijal\Branch\1.8.0.0\Cotrijal\Servicos\SACG.Services.Integracao\Integracao\Utils.cs:line 176
   at SACG.Services.Integracao.Integracao.Utils.EnviarEmail[T](T processo, Int32 codigoDaUnidade, String mensagem, String assunto) in c:\Projetos\Cotrijal\Branch\1.8.0.0\Cotrijal\Servicos\SACG.Services.Integracao\Integracao\Utils.cs:line 114
   at SACG.Services.Integracao.Integracao.IntegracaoDaExpedicao.SalvarExpedicao(ExpedicaoGraos expedicaoDto, Usuario usuarioLogado) in c:\Projetos\Cotrijal\Branch\1.8.0.0\Cotrijal\Servicos\SACG.Services.Integracao\Integracao\IntegracaoDaExpedicao.cs:line 111
   at SACG.Services.Integracao.ExpedicaoDeGraos.RegistrarExpedicao(ExpedicaoGraos expedicao) in c:\Projetos\Cotrijal\Branch\1.8.0.0\Cotrijal\Servicos\SACG.Services.Integracao\ExpedicaoDeGraos.asmx.cs:line 104
```

Comment: what kind of exception was it throwing?

Comment: what do you try to accomplish?

Comment: Error message would be more helpful than the stack trace by itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try getting value of an object, instead of PropertyInfo:

```
(List<ItemDeMescla>)objeto.GetValue(processo, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
objeto.GetValue(processo, null)
```

Instead of

```
objeto.GetValue(objeto, null)
```

Comment: @I4V No he does `objeto.GetValue(objeto, null)`